# Windows deleting Ubuntu boot entry

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 17.10, windows-10

So recently within the past month or so, I've noticed that Windows seems to be deleting the EFI entry for Ubuntu every time I boot it.  I've had to run boot-repair every time to restore the ubuntu boot entry. I'm running a fully up to date Windows 10, and Ubuntu 17.10.  Does anyone know what could be causing this to happen?

My motherboard is a ROG MAXIMUS X HERO (WI-FI AC) running the 1003 BIOS, if that helps.

Comment: Did you do any searching at all? This has been answered a million times all over the Internet, including here.

Comment: I searched a bunch and only the related links on this question I made have even come close to offering a proper fix for the issue.  I'm looking at some of them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have no idea why this works, but I found a solution that seems to work reliably.

Previously, I had been switching OSes by rearranging the boot order so the OS I wanted was the first entry.  This strategy exhibits the issue.

If I instead select the Windows UEFI bootloader from GRUB, the issue does not occur.  After reconfiguring GRUB so it would remember the last boot entry picked, I now have a setup where I can easily switch between the OSes again and the last one I was running still sticks.